# How to make spaces between two button in material ui?

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying take my UPDATE and DELETE button to the same row.It comes.But there is no space between those two buttons.

```
              <Button className={clsx(classes.button)}
                type="submit"
                variant="contained">
                {'Update'}
              </Button>

              <Button className={clsx(classes.button)}
                type="submit"
                variant="contained">
                {'Delete'}
              </Button>   
            </div>
```

How could i fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You need Material UI [Box](https://material-ui.com/components/box/) Component for this with `display="flex"` and `justifyContent="space-between"`. This adds space between elements horizontally.

```
<Box display="flex" justifyContent="space-between">
  <Button className={clsx(classes.button)}
            type="submit"
            variant="contained">
            {'Update'}
          </Button>

          <Button className={clsx(classes.button)}
            type="submit"
            variant="contained">
            {'Delete'}
          </Button>   
</Box>
```

Comment: Thank you ... when I tried this ... it equally spaced my buttons horizontally across the whole page ... what I wanted was just a few pixels between the items.

Comment: Rather than using `Box` and making it `flex`, use `Stack` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Malsha Madushani,

if you want to create a space between buttons you can give one button a margin-attribute.

See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/eb94v8fq/

```
/*------------HTML------------*/
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            /*-------------CSS--------*/
            #buttons{
                background-color:red;
            }
    
            #updateBtn{
                margin-right: 100px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="buttons">
            <button id="updateBtn"
                    className={clsx(classes.button)}
                    type="submit"
                    variant="contained">
            {'Update'}
            </button>
            <button id="deleteBtn"
                    className={clsx(classes.button)}
                    type="submit"
                    variant="contained">
            {'Delete'}
            </button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You need to give the first button the styles attribute margin-right: (xx)px;

[button][button]

will create a 10px space between the two buttons.

result:

[button]---space(in px)---[button]

Answer (score 0):

my way

```
<Button className={classes.button} type="submit" variant="contained">
    Update
</Button>
<Box flexGrow={1} />
<Button className={classes.button} type="submit" variant="contained">
    Delete
</Button>
```